# JQuery: Iterate through an array by using on('click')

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, onclick, while-loop

I am trying to get into JQuery but am struggling a bit around.

What I'm trying to do is go through an array one click at a time so that each time I click on the "next" button a new item is presented.

Let's take a look at the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var stuff =["house","garden","sea","cat"];  
    for (var i=0; i<stuff.length;i++)
    {
        console.log(stuff[i]);
    }  
});
```

Now how I was thinking something like creating a while loop with i

```
$("#next").on('click', function(){i++;});
```

But this somehow doesn't work. 
Anyone able to explain to me how to do this in a relatively simple way?

Comment: A loop does not respond to user interaction. It always runs completely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run through your loop with the `for` statement, it does so immediately and not in response to an event.

Instead, you want to step through the array with each click.  To do so, you need to define a counter outside your click function and increment (or reset, if you've reached the end of the array) with each click.

Here is some sample code:

```
$(function () { // this is a shortcut for document ready
    var stuff = ['house', 'garden', 'sea', 'cat'],
        counter = 0;

    console.log(stuff[counter]); // your initial value

    // the next line, of course, assumes you have an element with id="next"
    $('#next').click(function () {
        counter = (counter + 1) % stuff.length; // increment your counter
        // the modulus (%) operator resets the counter to 0
        // when it reaches the length of the array

        console.log(stuff[counter]); // the new incremented value
    });
});
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Simply keep a counter outside your callback and increment it at each click :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;    
    var stuff =["house","garden","sea","cat"]; 
    $("#next").on('click' function(){
         i = (i+1)%stuff.length;
         console.log(stuff[i]);
    });
});
```

Comment: Short followup: What is the intention behind adding the "%stuff.length;"?

Comment: @Peter: `%` is the modules operator. `i` will be reset to `0` if it is equal to `stuff.length` ( `4 % 4 = 0`). This is often use to "wrap around" when iterating over an array, otherwise you would continue increasing `i` and no such elements exist in the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var currentPos = 0;

   $("#next").click(function()
   {
      currentPos++;
      printThings(currentPos);
   });
});

function printThings(maxLength)
{
   maxLength = maxLength > stuff.length ? stuff.length : maxLength;
   var stuff =["house","garden","sea","cat"];  
    for (var i=0; i<maxLength;i++)
    {
        console.log(stuff[i]);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to cycle in the opposite direction:

```
$("#prev").on('click', function(){
        stuff.reverse();
         i = (i+1)%stuff.length;
         console.log(stuff[i]);
    });
```

It works but it skips one value...

Answer (score -1):

I would add a text box to the form. Then, on your #next click function loop the array. While looping compare the array value to what is in the text box. When you get a match - change the value of the text box to the next array value in the loop, then exit the loop.

Comment: That sounds complicated and why would you use a textbox if you can just store the value in a variable? The OP does not even mention that they are using a form.